# Will later loading of phpmyadmin in Wampserver scrub database files I have created

Tags: wampserver

When I loaded Wampserver 2.4 onto my machine I opted not to load phpmyadmin. After using the program & creating various files including databases I now want to load phpmyadmin. Can this be loaded without scrubbing the other parts of Wampserver & the files & databases that have been created?

Comment: WAMPServer 2.4 is WAYYyyyyy out of date. I also dont remember an option to not load phpMyAdmin!

Comment: In case you think you can use the ADDON's they dont work with 2.4 they only work on V3 and above

Comment: But if you manually install phpMyAdmin it will have NO Effect on your existing databases. Its afterall a tool written in PHP its not a DBMS itself